# Paypal Mobile Payment Library and Mobile Express Checkout Library

Tags: paypal

I am planning to use Paypal's MPL or MECL in my app.

I found that MPL is easier process, which does not require my webserver's involvement.

The main question is - is it possible to accept direct credit/debit card payment with MPL or do I have to use MECL for that?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also working for MECL. But, not get any solution. I've finished 75%

Answer (score 2):

MPL currently does not support direct credit card payments, however MECL does.
See the link for library features:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-overview

Answer (score 0):

MpL is accepting payments through paypal account only
but MECL accepts from credit/debit cards..